# Como puedo introducir un codigo php dentro de un script dentor de un echo php

Tags: php

Hola buenas tardes me gustaria saber como se puede conseguir introducir un codigo php en un codigo script que se encuentra dentro de un echo php.

Código

```
$ContarP =$consultaProducto['id'];

echo'<script>

    var ID="<?php echo($ContarP);?>";
        alert(ID);

    </script>';
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No hay necesidad de hacer eso, no es recomendable. Lo mejor es hacer esto.

```
echo'<script>

    var ID="'.$ContarP.'";
    alert(ID);

</script>';
```